# What happens to props once a React project is built?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am building a project out in React and am coming up against a problem I don't know how to solve as conceptually it's beyond me.

In my project, I pass a JavaScript Date object in to a component as props.
Then I store this data as state in the component.
That date state is then used to update a timeline bar, which obviously needs to be current for the timeline to progress.

A simplified version of the code is below:

DateComponent file:

```
class DateComponent extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      start: new Date(this.props.start)
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div data-custom-attr={this.state.start}></div>
    )
  }
}
```

Passing props in:

```
<DateComponent
  start={new Date()}
/>
```

In my finished project I am going to have some HTML rendered like so:

```
<div data-custom-attr="date-string"></div>
```

Is there anyway I can get it so that if I then build the React project out, if I wanted to update the `data-custom-attr` with a new date, or to keep it returning the current date using plain JavaScript, it will perform the required operations as in the react environment?

Comment: " keep it returning the current date"  How often do you want it to update?

Comment: I want to make it return the current day we are on

Comment: It's going to calculate date whenever that component is mounted.  It's not clear to me why you are storing in state as well.  Do you have other functions that update that piece of state?  What exactly is the problem you are running into?

Comment: I agree with @jmargolisvt. `Props` will be **initialized/created** every time with your react web app is loaded, so I think don't have to worry about your date as you are thinking of the current day the page will show on the user's browser.

Answer (score 0):

To get this to update actively with props, you would need to either trigger a re-render because you are storing the props into state or use a lifecycle method like `componentWillUpdate` to catch the update at the parent level and `setState` again (I don't suggest using this lifecycle method since it is being deprecated by Facebook).

Personally, you just need to simplify your component. Rather than the DateComponent managing the date state, just extract that to the parent level and pass the date props directly to the html. Whenever start updates, this will update the DateComponent. For example:

Parent

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentDate = new Date()
    }
  }

  render = () => {
    const {currentDate} = this.state;
    return (
      <DateComponent start={currentDate} />
    )
  }
}
```

DateComponent

```
class DateComponent extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const {start} = this.props;
    return (
      <div data-custom-attr={start}></div>
    )
  }
}
```

The cool thing about this is that by simplifying the DateComponent to be static, this component can be simplified further. You can take advantage of some of the new features out there like context too, however, I won't get into that here.

static DateComponent

```
const DateComponent = ({start}) => (
  <div data-custom-attr={start}></div>
)
```